# maintaining vertical font space using CSS

Tags: css

Im using Lucida Grande font for my site and when I put the font-size large, say 30px, the fonts in the two adjacent lines overlap upto some extent. How can I put a gap between the two lines using CSS?

Comment: Are you specifying a line height in your CSS? are you using pixel sizes or %/EM sizing?

Comment: I specified line height only for h1, h2 and h3. I can't figure out why it should affect other texts outside those elements.

Comment: do you have any live example to check it? It would help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`line-height`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/line-height) property. Something like

```
p {
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
```

Should do. This will give you line height 1.3 times the font-size you set. You probably have this set to a fixed number, like `25px` in another ruleset or stylesheet, thus when you increase the font-size the line height does not increase with it.

Comment: Yes. i was about to accept this answer when a pop up says "You can accept this answer in 6 mins". Now I've accepted it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a fixed `line-height` set. Change it to be either relative (e.g., `line-height: 1.3em;`) or fixed, but larger (`30px`).

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
user same line-height as as font-size;
*/

.product{
 font-size:30px;
 line-height:30px;
}

/*
its always a better practice to define line-height in body if you are going to use same font size across or as standard
*/
```